# Cryptographically Secure Pin Generator using RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, random

In my system I have a SMS authentication. Users input their user-id and get sent an SMS with a 5 digit pin number they input in a website to log in. The pin has a lifetime of a few minutes.

This pin number needs to be fairly secure so hackers can't try to guess the pin.

I would like to get some comments about my approach and code.

### Here is my Code:

```
public class PinGenerator : IPinGenerator
{
    public string GetPin()
    {
        var rand = GetRandomNumber();

        return (rand %99999).ToString().PadRight(5, '0');
    }

    private int GetRandomNumber()
    {
        using (var crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[4];

            crypto.GetBytes(data);

            return Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside @rolfl Great answer you should still store the pin hashed with a salt. So even if the attackers can have a look to your database somehow, they can't use nor get the pin. I was reluctant to post this as an answer given that you don't say how you store your pin nor the code was included related to that, on your question.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Thank you, that is good advice!

Comment: @BrunoCosta Hashing is pointless for 5 digit pins. They're easily brute-forced, even with an expensive hash.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Is my 4 digit pin of my credit card stored on `blank`? If not you lost your argument. I hope it isn't.

Comment: @BrunoCosta I'm not an expert on credit cards. But I doubt the PIN is stored at all (not even hashed) on the magnet strip, since that'd remove the whole point of having a PIN. Storing it on a chip based card wouldn't be totally broken, because the chip aims to be a tamper-proof computer, not merely externally readable storage.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Meaning that if the attacker for some reason has access to the database, according to the same analogy, he also shouldn't be able to tell what the pin is just by looking at it. It is true that 10^5 attempts are easy to try but for that same reason we also should limit the number of attempts that can be made, just like the atm does by taking our cards in. Notice also that I meantioned a salted hash, not just any hash.

Comment: @BrunoCosta You can't limit the number of attempts for an attacker who can access the hashed value. Whereas with cards the PIN will only be stored on a server which can limit the number of attempts. Storing a hashed PIN on a magnet strip would be totally broken.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sorry I can now understand why. Even with salt the attacker has enough information to the in the worst case compute 10^5 hashes. Which doesn't really add plenty to the security. What if a pepper would be used as well? So now the attacker would need both database and source code access. The number of hash needed is the same but we are limiting attacks by increasing the amount of resources needed by the attacker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use unsigned integers to avoid the `Abs` related issues
- `RightPad` is incorrect, since shorter integers need *leading* zeros. Either use `LeftPad` or simply `ToString("D5")`
- A bigger integer will reduce the bias.

Thus I'd rewrite the relevant code as:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(UInt64)];
cryptoRng.GetBytes(buffer);
var num = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
var pin = num % 100000;
return pin.ToString("D5");
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that are problematic with respect to the actual randomness of the numbers.

First up, while this should not make a difference to the "randomness", you should rather declare your `crypto` instance as a static field. See [RandomNumberGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) This will prevent having to create a complicated construction process each time you need a PIN. `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is thread-safe.

OK, there's a bug in the `Math.abs(...)` mechanism because it does not handle `Int32.MinValue` correctly (See: [Math.abs(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx(v=vs.110).aspx). It would be better for you to do a simple bit-zero of your high-byte to unset the sign-bit:

```
data[0] &= 0x7f
```

Without that, you risk getting an exception in your method.

Your modulo computation is also wrong. I presume you want to allow any 5-digit pin, but doing `%99999` will return the values `0` through `99998`, and never `99999`. Your modulo should be `%100000`.

Finally, you should be using `PadLeft`, and not `PadRight`. If your resulting number is 5, you want the pin to be `00005`, and not `50000`. With your code the way it is, you will be getting a random skew in the sense that you will bever get results with leading zero's, and you will be getting an increased frequency of pins with trailing zeros.